# How to find whether HashMap is empty/null in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, hashmap, jstl

I have something like this in my controller:

```
model.attribute("hiringManagerMap",hiringManagerMap);
```

I am accessing this `hiringManagerMap` in my jsp and displaying the string values in option.

I need to display that field only when the Map is not null.

I tried doing `<c:if test=${!hiringManagerMap['empty']}>`. But, it doesn't work. It does not work even when the Map isn't empty.

Please help!!

Comment: Show us the code you tried using.

Answer (score 22):

Try this `<c:if test="${not empty hiringManagerMap}">`. It should check for both null and empty. Please read [this](http://gayleforce.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/jstl-empty-operator/) for more details if you need to check other collections or maps for being empty.

Comment: @Neha You should accept the answer if it resolved your concern otherwise people won't be willing to answer your questions in future due to low accept %.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<s:if test="#map.element != null">
         //you code
</s:if>
```

You need more code for this work but idea is similar.